# Extract Bold Text from JSON

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-api

I'm using Google API and GSC to get the bold from the htmlSnippet:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_term="search term in Google"

api_key=""

resource=build("customsearch", 'v1', developerKey=api_key).cse()

result=resource.list(q=search_term,cx=' ').execute()

for i in result['items']:
    html=str(i['htmlSnippet'])
    print(html)
```

So I get something like this:

```
Metadescription from Google in <b>bolds text</b>. Here there is <b>another bold</b>
```

Then I try with this:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    print(soup.find_all('b'))
```

**And it works but I can't get only the text.**

Trying with:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
    print(soup.find_all('b').text)
```

Doesn't work =/

Pleas help me!

Comment: `find_all` returns a list, you have to loop over it. Use `find()` if you just want to find the first one.

Answer (score -1):

`soup.find_all()` returns a list, you need to get the text of each of them in a loop.

```
print(b.text for b in soup.find_all('b'))
```